# getDeclaredConstructor doesn't find constructor with interface as parameter

Tags: java, reflection

I have an interface

```
public interface IDrawing
```

Next I have a class implementing this interface:

```
public class Line implements IDrawing
```

Now I have a class with a constructor that accepts above as parameter:

```
public LineChanger(Line line)
```

No problems there.

When I use reflection to call above constructor, it throws a NoSuchMethodException

```
//drawing variable is of class Line implementing IDrawing
.getDeclaredConstructor(IDrawing.class).newInstance(drawing);
```

The exception goes away when I change the constructor to:

```
public LineChanger(IDrawing line)
```

Is it possible to get the reflection working without changing the constructor?

I wish to keep the constructor strict (i.e. only accept one specific class in this case `Line`) but keep the reflection working for my factories.

Comment: The constructor only accepts `Line` objects. There is no constructor that accepts any `IDrawing` so its no surprise that you get an Exception when trying to get one with reflection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public LineChanger(Line line)
```

> When I use reflection to call above constructor, it throws a `NoSuchMethodException`

Only if you got it wrong.

```
//drawing variable is of class Line implementing IDrawing
.getDeclaredConstructor(IDrawing.class).newInstance(drawing);
```

You got it wrong. The type of the parameter is `Line.class`, not `IDrawing.class`.

> The exception goes away when I change the constructor to:

```
public LineChanger(IDrawing line)
```

Of course it does. When you do that, your Java code and your reflective code agree. If they don't, it can't work, can it?

> Is it possible to get the reflection working without changing the constructor?

Yes, call `.getDeclaredConstructor(Line.class).newInstance(drawing);`,provided `drawing` is an instance of `Line`.

You seem to be expecting miracles here.

Comment: Cheers @EJP  I don't know where my brain was this morning, it must be still in bed... Thanks for clearing things up! I'll keep this topic around cause the replies from Sweeper and Royal Bg are still interesting

Answer (score 4):

There is possibility to make it the way you want, if you traverse all constructors and find that one with exactly one parameter which is assignable from `IDrawing`.

```
    Constructor ctor = Arrays.stream(LineChanger.class.getConstructors())
            .filter(c -> c.getParameterCount() == 1)
            .filter(c -> c.getParameterTypes()[0].isAssignableFrom(IDrawing.class))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(LineChanger.class.getConstructors()[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call `getConstructor`, the API will find the constructor with exactly that signature, so if there isn't a constructor taking an `IDrawing` parameter, your code throws an exception.

It does not make sense for the API to behave like you expected anyway. You can't pass an object of type `IDrawing` to a parameter of type `Line` because the object you passed can be any implementation of `IDrawing`.

However, the reverse is possible, you can pass an object of type `Line` to a constructor taking `IDrawing`. Here is a method that finds all the constructor that a given set of types can be passed to.

```
public static List<Constructor<?>> getCompatibleConstructors(Class<?> clazz, Class<?>... parameterTypes) {
    Constructor<?>[] ctrs = clazz.getConstructors();
    ArrayList<Constructor<?>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    outer: for (Constructor<?> ctr : ctrs) {
        if (ctr.getParameterCount() == parameterTypes.length) {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < parameterTypes.length ; i++) {
                if (!ctr.getParameterTypes()[i].isAssignableFrom(parameterTypes[i])) {
                    continue outer;
                }
            }
            list.add(ctr);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

It can find this constructor:

```
 public MyClass(IDrawing drawing) {}
```

if you pass these arguments:

```
 getCompatibleConstructors(MyClass.class, Line.class);
```